# Would it be possible to lower the amount of reputation that is required to comment? What is the process for changing this?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I joined Stack Overflow as a casual user, in order to vote on content, answer some questions that don't receive answers (which I am able to answer), and to comment where need be (such as when an answer doesn't work under certain circumstances).

I've already been told that having reputation before commenting is required to reduce unnecessary comments and stop spam.

Regardless of whether 50, 30, 20, or 15 reputation is required to comment, I can't see this making much, if any, difference in the current quality of comments.

As is stated in the title, is it possible to reduce this amount? Before I had enough reputation, there was a number of times where I wanted to comment and couldn't do so. Specifically for notifying other users about cases where their solutions wouldn't work. I can do all of this now, but there are other people who are, or will be, affected by this.

Comment: Let's be honest. 50 reputation takes a trivial amount of time to achieve. That's two accepted (and upvoted) answers. Or 5 upvotes. If someone is unable or unwilling to achieve this, it's very unlikely they'd be wanting to participate in the community, anyway.

Comment: @Rob Why do you assume that it's trivial? New users need time to figure out how things work. Also, it's not as simple as you make it sound. There are many things that affect how much reputation you get and how long it takes to get it. Sometimes an op says an answer's right, but doesn't do anything, only votes it up, or only votes it as correct. Some people on the site are quick to down vote making it harder. I've seen a number of questions and answers that didn't have any problems down voted. Furthermore, if you take the time to test and run your code, that takes longer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/

Comment: @DaveF It's trivial because the only reason you'd want reputation is to be able to contribute to the community. In order to get that reputation, you need to contribute to the community *anyway*. 50 reputation would only take a few hours commitment. If that's too much time to put in, then having reputation to comment really isn't that important. If answering questions is giving you trouble, you can always edit and clean up posts, getting you 2 rep for each approved edit.

Comment: @Rob Making people do more work than is necessary because you think it proves loyalty is disrespectful and egocentric. There is no added benefit to making the required reputation higher than what is required to block spam.

Comment: @DaveF And now we're back to the position where you need to *prove* that lowering the reputation is beneficial to the site, rather than you simply wanting it 'just because'. No one is *making* anyone do any work. Why would anyone want reputation on SO if contributing was not enjoyable anyway?

Comment: @Rob I've already given examples about correcting questions and asking for more information. Also, there are posts on Meta Stack Overflow about people posting comments using answers because they can't comment. Allowing people to comment sooner reduces abuse and improves answers.

Answer (score 18):

Do you know how many accounts there are with less than 50 reputation on Stack Overflow?

## **4.9 *million***.

Do you know how many accounts have at *least* 50 reputation?  A mere 193K.

Given that there are so many different attempts at spam and inappropriate behavior here, having 50 reputation to shield us from the vast majority of spammy or inappropriate comments is important.

It may not do anything for the *quality* of comments; I doubt that any measure could do anything about that.  But it absolutely can do something to ensure that we don't get inundated with porn and virus links.

Comment: Why do you assume that 50 is needed? It could easily be less. Answering questions isn't going to be done by a bot. A human needs to do it. Why would anyone waste their time here answering any questions in order to put spam in the comments when there are easier avenues elsewhere.

Comment: @DaveF:  Why do you feel that it should be less?  What's wrong with getting 50?  Why would anyone feel that it's a waste of time and still want to be a part of the community?

Comment: Why are so many people insistent on 50? I haven't seen a legitimate answer against lowering the amount. Some people want to help others because they've gotten help and they don't necessarily want to spend more time on here than what they need to. Lowering the required reputation means people can help using comment, in the appropriate way, sooner.

Comment: @DaveF:  It's a good barometer of general participation.  It's five answer upvtotes or ten question upvotes.  It determines and demonstrates that someone wants to really contribute to the community and is capable of doing so in a positive way.  I see no reason to lower the limit and there's not much that you've said that would convince me otherwise.

Comment: The question was why not another number? Your response doesn't answer the question (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring_%28fallacy%29). So far I haven't seen one that does. An answer similar to, "We've tried other values, but the amount of spam that is posted in comments increases as the reputation that is required to comment is lowered," would be a good answer. Even the answer, "It was introduced in an attempt to stop spam. That's what was decided on and the moderators don't want to change it," is still an answer. It might be a poor reason for the value but it would be an answer.

Comment: If it hasn't been tried and can be done fairly easily, it would make sense to test the effect that lowering the reputation that is required to comment has. If it's problematic, then you raise it again.

Comment: "Why not another number?" ......honestly if we could change it, it really should be raised, not lowered.

Comment: Are you able to query Stack Overflow information? I'm wondering how many of the 4.9 million accounts had a reputation of less than 40, 30, 20, and 10. That would be a good indicator of whether or not you could lower the reputation required for commenting. It would also answer how necessary the 50 reputation is.

Comment: @patricksweeney Why? If what Makoto said was accurate, there isn't any reason to raise it unless it affects having to stop spam.

Comment: @DaveF If you're going to propose changing a core feature of the site, the burden is on **you** to demonstrate that a change is necessary, and that it would have a positive effect, not on everyone else to demonstrate that your proposed change *wouldn't* be beneficial.

Comment: @DaveF Anyone can query stack overflow information: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/435078

Comment: @Davef More visual : https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/435081#graph

Comment: @DaveF:  [Here's a slightly better query to use.](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/434444) If you want to dig deeper into it, you're welcome to adjust the query.

Comment: @Servy I've already given examples about correcting questions and asking for more information. Also, there are posts on Meta Stack Overflow about people posting comments using answers because they can't comment. Allowing people to comment sooner reduces abuse and improves answers.

Comment: @DaveF:  **You have no evidence to indicate this.** If you did, it would be in your question.

Comment: @Servy Why would the burden be on me to answer my own question? And we're not talking about about anything significant. It's probably one field in a database.

Comment: @Rob 3.1 million users have 1 reputation and are most likely spammers. I didn't see any columns that can be used to determine accounts that may have been disabled (or flagged or something else) as spam accounts or anything similar for posts. Without that I can't get reliable results for making any inferences about the correlation between reputation and spam accounts.

Comment: @Makoto For correcting questions and asking for information, I was referring to myself. However, I didn't notice a reference to the latter in my question or comments so I may have made that statement in my previous question that I deleted. Regarding, answers as comments I can't find the posts that I was looking at earlier to add links to them because searching using the terms "answers" and "comments" brings up posts about people answering questions in comments. I'm not going to bother searching further at this point because nothing useful will come from it.

Comment: I've seen a few 'answers instead of comments because cannot comment yet'.  I've seen a few spam entries.  Subjectively, I would say I've seen about the same number of both, (note - I understand that a large number of spams are filtered out before I could get to see them, I'm just referring to those that make it to SO main site somehow).   To me, that says that SO have set the rep level for comments about right.  I would not vote for it to be reduced,  I would not vote for it to be increased.